# Catch Unauthorized exception

Tags: c#

I am connecting to a webservice in my project by entereing user credentials(user name and password) i need to catch a unauthorized exception when the user enter invalid username/password. How can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you attempting to catch an exception before calling the webservice?

```
try
{
    result = Service.GetResult(param1, param2);
}
catch(System.Net.WebException ex)
{
    Logger.WriteError("Error calling Webservice: ", ex.ToString());
}
```

WebException will catch server return codes as errors I believe, such as HTTP status 404: Not Found etc.

Comment: i need to catch the exception at the calling method. Is it ok if i use the below method by checking the message text and if it is "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized." i will have my custom message

Comment: You could do that. You could then rethrow a custom exception and wrap the original exception into it - something like UnauthorizedWebException perhaps?

Comment: Do you also control the Webservice? i.e. can you make changes to it and re-release it?

Answer (score 0):

Is your web service SOAP? Are you using WCF on on the service side? If so, take a look at a [Specifying and Handling Faults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733721.aspx)

Comment: Well, I can't help you with asmx.  Good luck!