# Unable to Catch Unauthorized exception

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

In the webservice the following Post call is made.

```
try{
User = await _service.Post<User>("api/authenticate", model);
}
catch(Exception ex){
Console.Writeline($"exception{ex.Message}");
}
```

In the Controller if the user name or password is wrong it results in a unauthorized.

```
return Unauthorized(new{message = "PW wrong"})
```

or the user object

```
return Ok(user);
```

The service is able to catch a

```
return BadRequest();
```

response but not the Unauthorized response.

I was wondering if their is a difference between those responses.

I tried already to use System.Net.WebException like in this answer on [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721095/catch-unauthorized-exception)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Http error codes don't throw exceptions You might want to go through this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097730/usage-of-ensuresuccessstatuscode-and-handling-of-httprequestexception-it-throws

Comment: its weird because when i return badrequest it will be catched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

throw a Custom JSON HTTP response error and catch it